# Show breadcrumb on product details page

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I'm customizing rwd theme. I'm not able to show breadcrumb on product page.

In admin breadcrumb is enabled for CMS pages. Inside rwd/default/layout/page.xml

```
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

is present.
Even I tried adding

```
<block reference="header">
   <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

to default handle in page.xml

Inside catalog/product/view.phtml I've tried following codes

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
```

Still it's not appearing on product page.

Comment: by default magento product view page has 1 column layout and breadcrumbs are called from this file.so just check 1-coloum layout file has <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?> if not add ther and check.

Comment: product view page in magento by default has breadcrumds on the detail page

Answer (score 5):

In default rwd theme the breadcrumbs are coming on product details page.

### Check at Template file:

Basically magento calls the breadcrumb in root template files `1column.phtml`, `2columns-left.phtml` etc. using the code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>` .

### Check at page.xml

And on `page.xml`  it defines the breadcrumb block. You need to check this at thing on product details page.

### Check at other layout file:

You need check any layout code that might remove the breadcrumb using below code:

```
<catalog_product_view>
...
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
...
</catalog_product_view>
```

**or**

```
<catalog_product_view>
...
<reference name="root"> 
....               
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
...    
</reference>
...
```

Comment: + 1 amit for answer with nice explanation

Comment: @Amit: I see it's present in page.xml and 1column.phtml also. When I see page source readcrumb div is loading but title and links are null. `<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
                    <li class="">
                           <a href="" title=""></a>
                                       <span> </span>
                        </li>
                    <li class="">
                           <a href="" title=""></a>
                              <span> </span></li>
                    <li class=""><strong></strong>
                                    </li>
            </ul>
</div>`

Comment: You can check it [here](http://s19.dukano.co/index.php/accessories/af-0058-green-red-leather-footwear-4.html)

Comment: so where are this two files @amitshree

Comment: @vnnogile_user: it's an old thread. I think someone has added display:none; at that time.